# Can Google bots interpret hyphen separated words as a single keyword?

Tags: seo, url, search-engine-indexing, googlebot, google-index

I have a french website which frequently includes the word *rendez-vous*. But, Google Webmaster Tools content keywords tells me the #1 keyword is *rendez* which is not what I want. Even worse, the word *vous* is not even listed as a keyword (probably ignored). I do have the required meta (keywords/description).

I know the science of indexing is very complex, but is there something I can do so the content of my pages generate the proper keyword list? i.e. can a hyphen separated word become a single keyword.

I believe (for now) I have 2 options:

1. Leave it like that :(
2. Modify my URL to include *rendez-vous* to help the indexing

Answer (score 1):

Google seems to treat keyword with hyphen as pretty much the same as keyword without hyphen. In your case, 
Google considers *rendez-vous* as *rendez vous* and thus as *rendez* and *vous* as separate keywords.

But it's not a big deal; you're not losing traffic. Your website may show up on Google with all variant of 
keywords above.

It's like for keywords on URL: from a [Matt Cutts blog post](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/) (from 2005 sorry):

> If you have a url like word1-word2, that page can be returned for the searches word1, word2, and even 
>   “word1 word2″.

That's why I suggest you to keep your URL like that, especially if you mainly 
use on your website the combination *rendez-vous* as keyword, Google 
can understand *rendez-vous* as a keyword on its own.